# SQL like with select statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to use `LIKE` with an if statement, like so:

```
SELECT orders.[order#] 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.[order#] LIKE *(SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE .. = ..)*
```

The statement above results in a syntax error in Access 2016.

Comment: something like this will work `..orders o join (select.. from.. where) t on o.[order#] like t.col`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT o.[order#]
FROM orders o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM . . .
              WHERE o.[order#] LIKE <whatever>
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider an implicit join using `LIKE` statement (or cross join with filter):

```
SELECT orders.[order#] 
FROM orders, (SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE .. = ..) AS t
WHERE orders.[order#] LIKE '*' & t.Col & '*'
```